# Image is not displayed in overridden woocommerce email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I have overridden woocommerce *customer-completed-order.php*

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
?>

<p><?php printf( __( "Your recent order has been completed.<br> ,'woocommerce' ) ); ?></p>
```

How to add image to the end of the email?

I tried

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096 ,add_image_size('logo-size', 219,98) );  ?>
```

but only white space is displayed in the received email.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096); ?>
```

displays it in a cropped size.

**EDIT** added full *customer-completed-order.php*

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name']; // product name
}
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 * 
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
?>

<p><?php printf( __( "Your recent order has been completed, 'woocommerce' ), $product_name ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works.

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name']; // product name
}
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 * 
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
?>

<p><?php printf( __( "Your recent order has been completed, 'woocommerce' ), $product_name ); ?></p>

<p>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096, array('219', '98'), "", array( 
    'name' => 'logo',
    'align' => 'left', // Not supported in HTML5
    'border' => '0', // Not supported in HTML5
    'width' => '219',
    'height' => '98'
  ) ); ?> 
</p>
```

After adding

```
<p>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096, array('219', '98'), "", array( 
    'name' => 'logo',
    'align' => 'left', // Not supported in HTML5
    'border' => '0', // Not supported in HTML5
    'width' => '219',
    'height' => '98'
  ) ); ?> 
</p>
```

The images are displayed in email.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachement_image` wants the second argument to be an array of width, height

like:
array('900', '1200').

So in your example if attachment id is 1096, width is 219, and height is 98, it would be:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096, array( 219, 98) );  ?>
```

If you're looking for the un-cropped, full image:
Instead of using `wp_get_attachment`, try `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and pass a size argument of "full."

This returns an array:

> (false|array) Returns an array (url, width, height, is_intermediate),
>   or false, if no image is available.

So we get the url like so:

```
$attachment_id = '1906';
$image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
echo '<img src="'. $image_array[0] .'" >';
```

Comment: hi, thanks. tried your option with wp_get_attachment_image_src. image is still not seen. (

Comment: Hmm... did you try the `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096, array( 219, 98) );  ?>`

Comment: yes, the same effect

Comment: Can you post your complete version of _/customer-completed-order.php_ ?

Comment: Ok.. I do not see `do_action(footer)` etc., More importantly, I don't see where you are placing the not working  `wp_get_attachement`... you're asking about.